# Join different controllers from different projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, localhost

How can i use different controllers(MVC feat API) from different project(Project Only for MVC Controllers and another only for API Controllers) in one Main Project( on one localhost) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about ASP.NET MVC applications (which is not very clear from your question) you could reference the assemblies containing those controllers in a single ASP.NET MVC application and use them as normal controllers. One possibility is to have all the ASP.NET MVC applications in a single Visual Studio solution where you would reference them in the target application or reference the compiled assemblies from some location.

Of course with this you will also need to copy the corresponding view to the `~/Views` folder of the target application otherwise they might not be resolved. There are some techniques that allow you to reuse ASP.NET MVC views across different applications such as the [`Razor Generator`](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) package.

Comment: yes, about mvc) thanks. i think it would be more difficult)

Comment: Controllers are just simple classes that you could reuse by simply referencing the assemblies containing them. What is more challenging is reusing the views that they are depending on.

Comment: i have 2 projects : MVC4 Internet App & MVC4 WebAPI. So i add reference from WebAPI project to InternetAPP project and run, but api controller wasn't found...

Comment: But ASP.NET MVC Controllers are different than ASP.NET Web API Controllers. They do not derive from the same class and cannot be mixed.

Comment: so it's imposible to add api controll to mvc controlles?

Comment: They are of distinct types and are not designed to be mixed.

Comment: can you suggest how can i use api controllers in my internet app if they are not in one project?

Comment: A Web API is meant to be consumed over HTTP. So you should host the application containing your API controllers separately and then you could have multiple standard ASP.NET MVC applications sending HTTP requests to it.